# jQuery ScrollTop multiple links issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

The code below works fine when done this way.

```
                $('#privacyPolicy').click(function(){
                $('wrapper, div').animate({scrollTop:$('#privacyPolicy' + 'link').offset().top - 230}, 'slow');
            });
```

But I need it to work with multiple links?
I have tried this:

```
                $('#contents a').click(function(){
                $('wrapper, div').animate({scrollTop:$('id' + 'link').offset().top - 230}, 'slow');
            });
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for any help here.

Comment: I just found out what I was doing wrong I needed to change '#' + $(this).attr('id').

Comment: Thanks great! I suggest that you now accept Rab's answer and add that proper comment there, as it was Rab's suggestion to add # prefix for 'wrapper'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `each`

```
  $('#contents a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
    $('#wrapper, div').animate({scrollTop:$('id' + 'link').offset().top - 230},   'slow');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with replacing this line:

```
$('wrapper, div').animate({
     scrollTop:$(this.id + 'link').offset().top - 230
}, 'slow');
```

### note:

just seen this `$('wrapper` this should be prepended with id notation `#` or class notation `.`